# Data not passed in props to child componenets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-state

I have passed the data coming from the api (which is served in the Heroku server) as a props to child component using spread operator. The data is not rendered in the ui. There is no any error showing though. I am not sure what is the issue.

My ContactCards.js

```
function ContactCards() {

  const[contacts, setContacts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://texas-crm1.herokuapp.com/api/contactinfo')
      .then (res =>{
        console.log(res.data[0])
        let data = res.data[0];
        // setContacts (res.data[0])
        setContacts(contacts => { 
          return[
               
                      {
                        thumbnail: clock,
                        title: "Opening Times",
                        data1: contacts.open_hour,
                        data2: contacts.close_hour,
                      },
                      {
                        thumbnail: telephone,
                        title: "Phone",
                        data1: contacts.phone_1,
                        data2: contacts.phone_2,
                      },
                      {
                        thumbnail: location,
                        title: "Location",
                        data1: contacts.street_name,
                        data2: contacts.city + ", " + contacts.state + ", " + contacts.country,
                      },
                    ]
        });

      })  
      .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
      })
  },[])


return (
    <div>
      <div className="contact-cards">
        {contacts.map((contact) => {
          return <ContactCard {...contact}  />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>  
    );
}

export default ContactCards;
```

Here I have used ...contact as a spread operator as a props.

My ContactCard.js

```
function ContactCard(props) {
  const {thumbnail,title,data1,data2} = props;
  return (
    <div className="contact-card">
         <div className="container">
           <div className="thumbnail">
             <img src={props.thumbnail} alt={props.thumbnail} />
          </div>
           <div className="title">{props.title}</div>
          <div className="data">{props.data2}</div> 
          <div className="data">{props.data2}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}




export default ContactCard;
```

Here I have defined props to a const and defined all the props inside. Here only thumbnails are rendered but no other data. thumbnail and title are static data whereas data1 and data2 are coming from the api. Hope I have expalined well.

[image]

Here in the above picture, the thumbnails are displayed & on data2, undefined are displayed. Other data in the first two thumbnails are empty.

Comment: Did you try changing `contacts.map(...)` with `contacts.length > 0 && contacts.map(...)`, so that the ContactCard components are mounted only if there are actual contacts?

Comment: No there are acutal contents coming... I called the api in the browser, the data are there. In my data2, it shows undefiend. why it is saying undefined??

Comment: i have posted the pic, you can have a look at it.

Comment: can you try this <ContactCard props= {...contact} /> and in child ContactCard({props})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://texas-crm1.herokuapp.com/api/contactinfo')
    .then (res =>{
      console.log(res.data[0])
      let data = res.data[0];
      setContacts(contacts => { 
        return[
          {
            thumbnail: clock,
            title: "Opening Times",
            data1: contacts.open_hour, // <--- it should be data.open_hour
            ...
          },
          ...
        ]
      });
    })  
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err)
    })
},[])
```

`contacts` refers to the current state, which is initialize to an empty array, therefore `contacts.xyz` is always going to be `undefined`. What you should have instead is:

```js
...
setContacts([
  {
    thumbnail: clock,
    title: "Opening Times",
    data1: data.open_hour,
    ...
  },
  ...
]);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

try passing your props directly, not spreading them to the component. And render them if the data is available.

Edit: since you have predefined the contacts to be an empty array, you have to check its length.

```
return (
    <div>
      <div className="contact-cards">
        {contacts.length > 0 && contacts.map(
           ({thumbnail, title, data1, data2}) => 
               <ContactCard thumbnail={thumbnail} title={title} data1={data1} data2={data2}  />;
           )}
      </div>
    </div>  
    );
```

As for the ContactCard component, this was not an issue but for the sake of learning, you can access props like this aswell. makes the code a bit more readable.

```
function ContactCard({thumbnail,title,data1,data2}) {
  
  return (
    <div className="contact-card">
         <div className="container">
           <div className="thumbnail">
             <img src={thumbnail} alt={thumbnail} />
          </div>
           <div className="title">{title}</div>
          <div className="data">{data2}</div> 
          <div className="data">{data2}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Using spread operator to pass props is a perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: That is not the issue, the issue is the OP is not passing the data received from the API call to the state; `data1: contacts.open_hour` (contact is an array, therefore `contacts.open_hour` is always going to be undefined) should be `data1: data.open_hour`